# started animation render- how to stop it without losing what has been rendered so far?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have been rendering a 4000 frames animation and it is still going for 3 days now. Can I stop rendering and retain the mov. file (for the part that has been rendered) without risking to lose all the render? this is because I need to submit the animation even if it in progress or partial ..

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, that's why using jpg instead of movies is convenient, you can stop and relaunch whenever you want

Comment: moonboots : Also, if Blender or the computer crashes, you don't loose the rendered frames. And it allows multiple computers work on the same animation (using a shared folder and the "placeholders/don't owerwrite" settings).

Comment: press esc and blender should round up and still present you a working video file, but as said above, it is recommended to use images.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible, that's why using jpg instead of movies is convenient, you can stop and relaunch whenever you want. Also, as said by Thibsert, "if Blender or the computer crashes, you don't loose the rendered frames. And it allows multiple computers work on the same animation (using a shared folder and the "placeholders/don't owerwrite" settings)".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with moonboots about rendering image files, but I use PNG because it is a lossless format and it will preserve transparency if you need it which is great for composting in another program like Hitfilm.

Answer (score 0):

I think even if you're rendering in a video format you won't lose your file, if you stop in between. I say so just because today while I was rendering something, and wanna stop it in between due to some reason. Fortunately, the frames which had already rendered were still there in a video format.